# Connecting a BroadcastConnectedStream to AsyncIO

Tags: apache-flink

I need to make an AsyncIO rich function perform calls based on the latest set of rules. For operations like map I was able to process a BroadcastConnectedStream with a rich function by following this blog post: https://flink.apache.org/2019/06/26/broadcast-state.html

However, creating an AsyncIO function requires a DataStream as an input, which the BroadcastConnectedStream isn't (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/BroadcastConnectedStream.html)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could work around this limitation? The scenario is that I want an async function to stash incoming messages in the state when there's a non-transient error with an async call to the outside world, and resume operation once a "go-ahead" message is received on kafka (which I though I could do with a broadcast stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible to put a BroadcastProcessFunction (not a keyed one) in front of an async i/o operator, but you'd have to union in the other stream(s) you are processing, since async i/o only has a single input. Given how ugly that is, finding some other way to communicate the "go ahead" signal might be preferable.

Or you might want to look at [Stateful Functions](https://statefun.io), which has more flexibility in this area.

Comment: Stateful functions is exactly how I achieved it, thanks David. I have a StatefulMatchFunction that can handle incoming messages, async call results and go-ahead messages, plus it doesn't mind any looping

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, `AsyncFunction` does not support the Keyed state, so You will have to work around that too and implement this by Yourself by `CheckpointedFunction`.

Generally, I don't think that there is anything out-of-the-box You can use for this case. The best idea I can think of if You want to use `broadcast` would be to use the `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` to emit results down the stream and then use the AsyncIO function. If You implement Your own state handling then You can keep all the results that have failed and simply retry them.

However, just getting all requests as list and looping through them to retry is probably not the best idea as this can probably cause performance drawback (You set how many requests should be in progress at the same time, but this request would actually last a lot longer than others).

Comment: Thanks for your help. When KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction emits results downstream, will those get to all instances of the subsequent AsyncIO operator, or just one? If it's just one, then I suppose I could key this stream and thus match the broadcasted message to the right stateful AsyncIO instance. 
I see what you mean about there being this one AsyncIO request with all those failed messages that need to be retried -it will time out for the wrong reasons. Maybe instead of making a retry call there and then, I push the retries back onto the incoming stream, after the KeyedBroadcastProcessFun.?

Comment: Since `broadcast` basically means that the elements from the broadcasted stream will be  sent to all downstream instances (i.e. all parallel operators) this means that if You emit this element then it will be emitted to all AsyncIO operators (parallel ones). You can technically put the elements back to the stream (for exmaple using Kafka topic for retries), but even then You can't simply tell Flink to stop reading this data, so You would retry the failed requests all the time and push them back to Kafka, so perhaps the better idea would be to simply use something like backoff retries.

Comment: This kinda depends on what failure means in Your case i.e. if all requests are being made to the same service then there is probably no big difference between exponential backoff or other retry strategy and the pushing the elements to KafkaTopic. But, since there is only a limited number of requests that are in progress, if there can be a situation that some requests may fail and some may not (i.e. they are served by different services) then it's much better to use Kafka Topic or other form of "non-blocking" retries.